# Using a locally built libOSMesa to enable WebGL in Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, webgl

Well, I wanted to try to check out WebGL on Firefox (v38.0.5 on Linux); and I realized that in `about:config`, `webgl.osmesalib` was set to `/usr/lib/libOSMesa.so.6`, while `about:support` claimed:

```
Graphics
--------

Adapter Description: Tungsten Graphics, Inc -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) IGD GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT x86/MMX/SSE2
Device ID: Mesa DRI Intel(R) IGD GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT x86/MMX/SSE2
Driver Version: 1.4 Mesa 7.10.2
GPU Accelerated Windows: 0/1 Basic Blocked for your graphics card because of unresolved driver issues.
Vendor ID: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
WebGL Renderer: Blocked for your graphics card because of unresolved driver issues.
windowLayerManagerRemote: false
AzureCanvasBackend: cairo
AzureContentBackend: cairo
AzureFallbackCanvasBackend: none
AzureSkiaAccelerated: 0
```

So, I found [Blocklisting/Blocked Graphics Drivers - MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers), which notes:

> Mesa drivers are whitelisted if the Mesa version is at least 7.10.3 (see bug 659560).
>
> Exception: with the Nouveau 3D driver, the Mesa version is required to be at least 8.0 (see bug 729817)

Right, so `libOSMesa.so.6` doesn't actually check out with `1.4 Mesa 7.10.2`, but I thought I'd rebuild from source anyways.

So I got the source of 7.10.3 (`MesaLib-7.10.3.tar.gz`, `MesaGLUT-7.10.3.tar.gz`) and `libdrm-2.4.24`, unpacked, ran `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/Mesa-7.10.3/libdrm-2.4.24 ./configure --enable-gl-osmesa` and `make`, and indeed, I do get shared library files built libOSMesa.so -> libOSMesa.so.7 -> libOSMesa.so.7.10.3; and if we doubt the [version info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/viewing-linux-library-executable-version-info) in the filename, we could also try this:

```
$ strings -a lib/libOSMesa.so.7 | grep 'Mesa 7'
%u.%u Mesa 7.10.3
OpenGL ES-CM 1.%d Mesa 7.10.3
OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 7.10.3
```

Nice, so now I thought, I'll just replace this library as `webgl.osmesalib`:

[image: test.png]

... and run Firefox with:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/Mesa-7.10.3/lib LD_PRELOAD=/path/Mesa-7.10.3/lib/libOSMesa.so.7 strace /path/to/firefox -P default -safe-mode -new-instance 2>&1 | grep --color=always 'Mesa.*\.so'`

... and `strace` even tells me the library has been opened:

```
open("/path/Mesa-7.10.3/lib/libOSMesa.so.7", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

... and still - I get this in `about:support`, the same as above:

[image: test2.png]

So, it's still referring to Mesa 7.10.2, regardless - and I have no idea why?

Btw, I just now realized that the config setting `webgl.osmesalib` may be something hanging in my profile from earlier versions, because if I start `firefox` with default profile and safe mode, all I get is `gfx.blacklist.suggested-driver-version` and `gfx.prefer-mesa-llvmpipe` settings:

[image: test3.png]

So - how can I persuade firefox, to try the newly built Mesa libraries, instead of the old ones?

Comment: Related: [How to Enable WebGL for Blocked Graphics Cards in Firefox](http://www.sitepoint.com/firefox-enable-webgl-blacklisted-graphics-card/)

Comment: What happens if you try setting `webgl.force-enabled` to true?  Also, is your graphics card driver also referencing the newly built Mesa libraries?  You might want to share with us what GPU you're using, and what drivers specifically (it might be [blacklisted](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers#Compiled-in_blacklist) in the current version...).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand now: as per [Enable OpenGL 2.0 and WebGL for Intel GMA3150 in Ubuntu](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/11/13/enable-opengl-2-0-and-webgl-for-intel-gma3150-in-ubuntu/), what this new Firefox sees as a Graphics driver, is not some specific file version, but that which is reported by `glxinfo`:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i "OpenGL version"
flushing GPU caches before/after each draw call
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.10.2
```

Then I configured again with a prefix `/usr` (otherwise the default is `/usr/local`), which is where Ubuntu Natty wants these stored; and did install:

```
./configure --enable-gl-osmesa --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
```

And then, just for a while, `glxinfo` returned `7.10.3`, which is what Firefox would have seen; but for one I ran out of disk space; and for another, now after reboot I get:

```
$ glxinfo 
name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

And this apparently ([graphics - Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475972/error-couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig-ubuntu-12-04)) requires messing with `xserver-xorg`, so it is a bit more complicated than just replacing the library, it seems...

---

Edit: actually got it: From this [Problems with nvidia drivers in 12.2 - glxinfo "couldn't find RGB GLX visual"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/suse-opensuse-60/problems-with-nvidia-drivers-in-12-2-glxinfo-couldn%27t-find-rgb-glx-visual-4175447410/), I learned to do:

```
$ grep -B2 EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
...
[    37.353] (II) AIGLX: Trying DRI driver /usr/lib32/dri-alternates/i915_dri.so
[    37.353] (II) AIGLX: dlopen of /usr/lib32/dri-alternates/i915_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/dri-alternates/i915_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[    37.353] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
...
```

I mentioned that I ran out of disk space; so I did this (after a `sudo make install` of Mesa):

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/dri /media/external/_mv/
sudo ln -s /media/external/_mv/dri /usr/lib/
sudo mv /usr/lib/egl /media/external/_mv/
sudo ln -s /media/external/_mv/egl /usr/lib/
```

Then we actually need to restart x-server, so it can "see" the .so files in the symlink locations upon load, which as per [How can I restart x-server from the command line? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-can-i-restart-x-server-from-the-command-line), for me was `sudo service gdm restart`

After that, got this:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :1.0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/local/lib/dri/i915_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/local/lib/dri/i915_dri.so failed (/usr/local/lib/dri/i915_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i915_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
....
```

... and simply did:

```
sudo ln -s /media/external/_mv/dri /usr/local/lib/
```

... and voila:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :1.0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/local/lib/dri/i915_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
flushing GPU caches before/after each draw call
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
...
```

... except, not even this is good enough for this Firefox:

[image: test.png]

Ah, well...